# Отсортировать вектор определенным образом

Tags: c++, сортировка, vector, char

Надо отсортировать вектор `ans` (тип `char`) в алфавитном порядке, при этом сначала должны идти буквы нижнего регистра, затем - верхнего. Честно пыталась найти решение в гугле, но почти все-с указателями. Можно без них решение, пожалуйста

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
// читайте сразу конец кода
int main() {
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    vector <vector <char>> pole(n, vector <char>(m)), pole2(n, vector <char>(m));
    string x, nada;
    vector <char> ans;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> x;
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            pole[i][j] = x[j];
        }
        x.clear();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> x;
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            pole2[i][j] = x[j];
        }
        x.clear();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (pole[i][j] != pole2[i][j]) { ans.push_back(pole[i][j]); }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ans.size(); i++) {
        if (ans[i] == '.') { ans.erase(ans.begin() + i); i = 0; }
    }
    cout << ans.size() << endl; 
    sort(ans.begin(), ans.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < ans.size(); i++) {
        cout << ans[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Этот код не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу. Что то еще хотели спрашивать?..

Comment: я залила весь код, чтобы было и объявление, и все видно.

Comment: Буквы только латинские?

Comment: да, большие и маленькие

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А без вашего кода?...

```
//функция сравнения
bool cmp(const char a, const char b)
{
    if (islower(a) && std::isupper(b))
        return true;
    else if (islower(b) && std::isupper(a))
        return false;
    return a < b;
}
//макрос для удобства
#define ALL(v) v.begin(),v.end()
//вводим, сортируем,удаляем повторяющийся символы и  выводим
int main() 
{  
    using Iter = std::istream_iterator<char>;
    std::vector<char>ans{ Iter(std::cin), Iter()};
    std::sort(ALL(ans), cmp);
    ans.erase( std::unique(ALL(ans)));
    std::copy(ALL(ans), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, " "));
    //Ну и можно освобождать лишнюю память(уменьшить 
   //занимаемый объем до нужного), если вектор еще где то нужен
   ans.shrink_to_fit();
   //...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: макрос хорош, сам такой придумывал, но только скобки не забываем `#define ALL(v) (v.begin()),(v.end())`. А ещё лучше так `#define ALL(v) begin(v),end(v)`

Comment: @KoVadim с 20 стандарта есть constrained алгоритмы без итераторов, так что такие макросы уже не нужны. Насчёт второго -- я уже говорил участнику про это (лучше писать `begin(x)`, а не `x.begin()`), но без результата

Comment: 20 стандарт только вот на днях приняли. и пока на него не сильно бы рассчитывал, особенно, если это задание в университете.

Comment: @KoVadim, begin(v),end(v) это для общего алгоритма, а для конкретных контейнеров, у которых есть свои begin  и end, в конкретном примере, ничего не меняет.  Что касается скобкам, тут они не нужны, не могу найти примера, где бы без скобок  раскрылось бы что то другое.

Comment: @dIm0n, да в  новом стандарте такой макрос не нужен. Что касается безрезультатности, то вы сами путаете общий алгоритмы с конкретной программой. Если вас слушать,то вообще не будут вызваны методы контейнеров.  Зачем они, если есть std::begin() и std::end()?... В комментариях я не смогу  приводить почему и когда лучше  пользоваться одним или другим инструментом, но я могу сказать о главной вашей ошибке: вы считаете, что вы всегда прав,  даже тогда, когда вы явно не правы.  Это вам всегда будет мешать продвигаться к лучшим результатам в познании и в общении с людьми.

Comment: Можно передать функцию, которая возвращает контейнер. и ... приплыли.

Comment: @KoVadim, верно, не подумал, спасибо, можно даже задать такой вопрос...

Comment: @KoVadim, Ну тогда `v`нужно  охватывать скобками

Comment: и даже если охватить скобками, все равно будет плохо. Очень плохо. Итераторы будут от разных объектов.

Comment: Спасибо, а что такое ```using Iter```, и что за ```unique```?

Comment: Это определение псевдонима типа,  unique  перемещает повторяющийся элементы в конец и возвращает итератор на  конец уникальных элементов